# 2017 developer survey doesn't have a final confirmation page

Tags: bug, survey-2017

After finishing the developer survey, and entering my profile URL, I get immediately redirected to [stackoverflow.blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/). It's somewhat jarring not to have a page confirming my submission, considering this is standard practice on most web forms.

Comment: I'm not sure that `bug` is the correct tag since the survey doesn't belong to the SO network.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: Well, it's not [meta-tag:discussion] or [meta-tag:feature-request], and I wouldn't call it [meta-tag:support] either.  So [meta-tag:bug] it is.

Comment: @Thomas the bug tag is accurate because the user believes that the behavior is not what it is supposed to be. The survey is produced by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

You should not be *immediately* re-directed to the blog.  Between the profile URL question and the re-direct, you should receive a page that says this:

> Thank you for completing the survey! We're looking forward to sharing the results with you and the rest of the community in March. If you provided your profile link, your badge will be awarded shortly after the survey closes at the end of January.
>
> In the meantime, you may close your browser tab now, or click on the "done" button below to be re-directed to our company blog.

Clicking the "done" button on that page should be what activates the re-direct to the blog.

Let me know if that's not appearing for you and we'll try to troubleshoot.  It would be helpful to know what you clicked on originally to start the survey -- i.e. if it was a banner ad on the site, a link from a blog post, something on Twitter, etc.

Comment: It was a link from the blog.